# Change my Link colors with CSS in asp.net

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I need some help changing my Link colors. This is currently my code for asp.net.

```
<div class="tile">
        <div class="first">
            <b>Links</b>
            <div class="links">
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink1" NavigateUrl="#ss" Text="Phone List" CssClass="linkbutton" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink2" NavigateUrl="#ff" Text="FAQ" CssClass="linkbutton" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="PMOLink" NavigateUrl="/PMO/PMO.aspx" Text="PMO" CssClass="linkbutton" runat="server" />
                <br />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="PMLink" NavigateUrl="/PM/PM.aspx" Text="PM" CssClass="linkbutton" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
    </div>
```

Here is my CSS code.

```
.first {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: left;
}

.links {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    height: 109px;
    width: 251px;
}

.tile {
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 14px;
    border-width: 3px;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 130px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px 40px 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    width: 270px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #CCF11B), color-stop(1, #3874FF));
    background-image: linear-gradient(-28deg, #CCF11B 0%, #3874FF 100%);
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Change the Links colors here!*/
linkbutton:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
}

linkbutton:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
}

linkbutton:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}

linkbutton:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
```

My **Result** should be when I hover over the Links, go to the said links, and just links in general, they should stay the same color and never change.I also was told it's easier to use CSS then C#. Can I get some help with this please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, you need to add the dot before the linkbutton class:

```
.linkbutton:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
}

.linkbutton:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: blue;
}

.linkbutton:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
}

.linkbutton:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
```

Comment: Thank you kindly. Can't believe I forgot the .

Comment: You're welcome. :) It can happen to everybody. I remember spending two hours of troubleshooting some programs for finding out a single semicolon was missing. The joy of coding...